# Scanner error - Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java.util.scanner

This code just reads the files which are perfect and correct but both the conditions `if` & `else if` give me error : `Scanner error - Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference`

```
  public void read(Map<String,String> dictionary,List<String> word){
        word = new ArrayList<>();
        dictionary = new HashMap();
        if(!FILE) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.word2));
            Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.def2));
            try {
                Scanner sc4 = new Scanner(openFileInput("addword.txt"));
                Scanner sc5 = new Scanner(openFileInput("adddef.txt"));
                while (sc4.hasNextLine() && sc5.hasNextLine()) {
                    String a = sc4.nextLine();
                    String b = sc5.nextLine();
                    dictionary.put(a, b);
                    word.add(a);
                }
                sc4.close();
                sc5.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            while (sc.hasNextLine() && sc2.hasNextLine()) {
                String a = sc.nextLine();
                String b = sc2.nextLine();
                dictionary.put(a, b);
                word.add(a);
            }
            sc.close();
            sc2.close();
        }
        else if(FILE) {

              Scanner scan = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.easy));
              while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                    String a = scan.nextLine();
                    if (!a.equals("")) {
                        String arr[] = a.split("~");
                        dictionary.put(arr[0], arr[1]);
                        word.add(arr[0]);
                    }}
                scan.close();
}}}
```

the errorlog are as follows :

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
>           at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
>           at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResourcesInternal(ContextThemeWrapper.java:127)
>           at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:121)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:542)
>           at com.example.ankitrath.WordTrivia.Settings.read(Settings.java:37)
>           at com.example.ankitrath.WordTrivia.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:51)

`Settings.java:37` refers to line below the *.
the method is used here as follows

```
ListView list;
ArrayAdapter<String> adap;
List<String> word = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,String> dictionary;
private String que="",ans="";
int counter=0;
private int hi = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//will hide the title
    getSupportActionBar().hide(); //hide the title bar
    dictionary = new HashMap<>();


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);


    ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.listid))
    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bglist);
    Settings o = new Settings();
    o.read(dictionary,word);
```

Comment: Please show the code how you call Settings.read() method in GameActivity.onCreate() method.

Comment: please check the update :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is clear.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>
> ....
>
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:542)
>   at com.example.ankitrath.WordTrivia.Settings.read(Settings.java:37)

It tells us that you trying to use `Context` that is `null`.

Why it is `null`?

This line of the `Settings` class:

`Scanner sc = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.word2));`

where you are calling `getResources()` method as a method of `Settings` class tells us that  `Settings` class extends `Activity` class.

If it is true you should refactor the `Settings` class from inheritance `Activity` to make it contains an `Activity` as a member of a `Settings` class. Like this:

```
public class Settings {

    private final Activity activity;

    public Settings(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    ...

}
```

Plus you will need to refactor all calling of related to activity methods like `getResources()` method like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(activity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.word2));
```

It will definitely help you.
But as I can guess, the `Settings` class it is a real activity that you probably use in your application, so you will probably need to extract all code related to `read()` method to a separate class.

Comment: Thanks for the support... i did make another class(Reader.java) which has a constructor to assign activity and one method to take the boolean value from the settings and store it to the variable present in Reader class. Another method uses that boolean(Reader.java). the second method is called from another activity called Gameactivity... I got an error...Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive

Comment: @AnshulSharma I glad to help you, don't forget to mark this like the answer. About a new exception, it looks like a totally different issue. I can suggest you create a new question and post related code there.

Comment: Solved that one by myself! Thanks!